# Setup gpio 23 as shutdown & startup

Tags: gpio, input-device, device-tree

Followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/fivdi/onoff/wiki/Enabling-Pullup-and-Pulldown-Resistors-on-The-Raspberry-Pi) & have included my device tree config below.  I've configured my pull up resistor for my button to function properly once my app is running, but I'm curious; **is there a way to change which pins are configured to create a reset (on button press) rather than 5&6?** I already have my connections soldered & would like to just reconfigure GPIO 23 (my button) to be able to shutdown/reboot.  Is this possible?  I'm new to electronics so the whole 'set high', 'set low' thing is new to me.

`raspberry pi model B`

`raspian jessie`

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2708";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&gpio>;
        __overlay__ {
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&my_pins>;

            my_pins: my_pins {
                brcm,pins = <23>;     /* gpio no. */
                brcm,function = <0>; /* 0:in, 1:out */
                brcm,pull = <2>;     /* 2:up 1:down 0:none */
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: I have never understood the point of a question when a simple test is enough to give a definitive answer (without the delay in waiting for an answer).

Comment: Yeah that would be fine if I knew how to test it.  You're saying that the config I have right now should work?  Cause guess what...it doesn't...

Comment: "I've got this working just fine"?